# How can I give preference to certain keys of keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard

When I play Tekken 3(with NAMCO emulator) on PC the player who keeps on pressing his keys halts other player's keys. I suppose it happens because more than two keys are pressed simultaneously.

My question is, is there some way in window-7 and window-10 via which the alphabetical keys gain higher preference than numeric keys on the right side of keyboard? The two simultaneous keys on the left side should also work.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to this is "no", as it's linked to the hardware and USB specs.  However, it's not on topic for this site, and so I am closing the question.  I'm not sure which site would be appropriate, but possibly SuperUser.

Comment: I wonder if just having 2 keyboards would work. This is possibly due to *how* the keyboard traces are laid out, and can't really be fixed in software.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If I attach a joystick would the keys be halted? Or computer(Emulator?) would take both the inputs simultaneously?